# How create a list of word lengths for the words in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

doesn't work for me in create list of word lengths ?

```
     str = "Python is a programming language"
     str = str.split()

     for char in str:
         len(char)
         char = words_in_list
  print(list(words_in_list))
```

i think output need to be like that 
        [6, 2, 1, 11, 8]

Comment: `lengths = list(map(len, str.split()))`

Comment: `print(list((len(word) for word in str.split()))`

Comment: On a different note: don't use `str` as the name of a variable, it's a builtin class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string = "Python is a programming language"
string = string.split()
my_list = []
for word in string:
    my_list.append(len(word))
print(my_list)
```